# How can I use Chrome WebDriver in another language

Tags: chromedriver

I want to be able to test with different languages.
How can I do that with chromedriver ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding Chrome's command line switches "--lang".

You start ChromeDriver with an ChromeOption argument, e.g. `--lang=es`

C# code for how to start Chrome in Spanish using Selenium:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--lang=es");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Java:

```
public WebDriver getDriver(String locale){   
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "driver/chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--lang=" + locale);
    return new ChromeDriver(options);
}

public void initializeSelenium() throws Exception{
    driver = getDriver("es"); // two letters to represent the locale, or two letters + country
}
```